# Examples of Design Patterns used in FOSS

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

I've read a lot of good things written about design patterns but am yet to actually look at things in detail. To me, design patterns is just a fancy name for data structures and algorithms. Before I invest any time in more reading, I'd like to see some good examples of design patterns working in real life.

What good examples of design patterns can I find in *well-known* open source projects?

*C++ preferred.*

**Update:** I see the close votes and downvotes. These were expected. If there is an alternative post with answers to my question, please lead me to it. At least leave a reason as to why this post doesn't belong here.

Comment: I was expecting close votes, downvotes. If there is an alternative question which answers my question, please lead me to it.

Comment: No one builds whole programs around one single design pattern. There are often dozens in play within a given program, and they don't necessarily leap out at you if you look for them. Design patterns aren't so obvious in source code -- they occur during, well, design.

Comment: @Chris, Where in my post did I say that whole programs are built from a single design pattern? Or did you read only the title of the post? Read again. Show me code which uses a design pattern. Code from a well-known open source project.

Comment: And the reason the post doesn't belong here is because you admit that you haven't taken the time to look at things in detail. Make an attempt, and if you get stuck THEN ask.

Comment: @Chris, Try answering the question. THEN tell me it doesn't belong here.

Comment: @Agnel: try asking a good question, THEN tell me to answer it.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621868/actual-usage-of-design-pattern-in-open-source-software

Comment: @Chris, That's much more useful. Thank you.

Comment: @Agnel: I... just... you could have searched for that yourself. In fact if you read the FAQ -- you should have searched for that yourself.

Comment: Your question, if it belongs somewhere, belongs on Programmers. Voted to close and move there.

Comment: As a side note to my answer, I can't help but agree that your question is rather poor. STL iterators are exactly what you asked for, and yet I'm sure it's not helping you in any way. This is a fairly exemplary case of a question that can't be reasonably answered in its current form.

Comment: Have you checked out [Wikipedia:Design Patterns][1] ? You will find a list of common patterns toward the end of the page.  These patterns are fairly pervasive and elements can be found in the Java libraries as well as Spring etc.




  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_pattern_%28computer_science%29

Comment: The other problem with this question is that generally design patterns aren't that well documented within open source projects. The code just kind of "exists". It's rare to see class diagrams and such that lets you clearly see what's going on. At least that's my experience.

Comment: @Colin, Yes. I did read the wiki article and much more than just that but I was not too impressed. The reason for this post was just to get some idea of how useful it can be before investing more time in it. Apologies if I come across as lazy but that is not the case.

Comment: @Agnel, No worries. I didn't pass judgement.

Answer (score 2):

It appears you did not invest enough time into design patterns to truly grasp what they are. I encourage you to read more, because design patterns are not a fancy name for data structures and algorithms; there is barely any link between algorithms and design patterns. Design patterns are "recipes" that help you organize classes and their relationships in a way that makes them easier to reuse.

As for examples, no need to look very far: the STL collection iterators are implementations of the [iterator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator_pattern).